# Correlation between a categorical nominal variable and a Likert item

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, ordinal-data, likert

How can I answer this question:

> Is there any relationship between teachers’ personality and their perceptions of principles of critical pedagogy?

Teacher personality consists of five type of personality
critical pedagogy consists of a Likert-scale (1-5).

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/73065/3277; http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23938/3277

Answer (score 1):

I would consider [an ordered probit](http://faculty.smu.edu/millimet/classes/eco6375/papers/becker%20kennedy.pdf) or logit model with dummy variables for each personality type. Here's [another example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44630/ordinal-probit-model-in-plain-english/44634#44634) of this type of model. This would allow you to express the probability that a teacher's perception of critical pedagogy is 1,2,3, 4, or 5 for each personality type and any additional characteristics.

If the personality measure is ordered, say from least authoritative to dictator, then methods that are simpler and more correlation-like can be used that take advantage of this.

---

**Citation for Ordered Probit:**

"A Graphical Exposition of the Ordered Probit" by William E. Becker and Peter E. Kennedy, *Econometric Theory*, Vol. 8, No. 1 (Mar., 1992), pp. 127-131